# Reading HttpContext.Request.Body with StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync or ReadToEnd Truncates Result

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, httprequest

I'm attempting to read the HttpContext.Request.Body into a local string variable as follows:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body,Encoding.UTF8))
{  
    var bodyContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    Log.Logger.Information("bodyContent before close = " + bodyContent);                            
}
```

The local string variable contains a JSON result but the last 2 curly braces are truncated from the end of the JSON.

I've also tried using httpContext.Request.BodyReader (System.IO.Pipelines.PipeReader) but the results are the same.

```
// This truncates more of the file at the end
// ReadAsync
httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();                                         
ReadResult bodyReadResult = await httpContext.Request.BodyReader.ReadAsync(); 
ReadOnlySequence<byte> bodyBuffer = bodyReadResult.Buffer;

if (bodyBuffer.Length > 0)
{
    byte[] bodyBytes = bodyBuffer.ToArray();
    string bodyText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);
} 

// This matches the ReadToEndAsync example above which removes the last 2 curly braces
// ReadAtLeastAsync
httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();                                         
ReadResult bodyReadResult = await httpContext.Request.BodyReader.ReadAtLeastAsync(10000); 
ReadOnlySequence<byte> bodyBuffer = bodyReadResult.Buffer;

if (bodyBuffer.Length > 0)
{
    byte[] bodyBytes = bodyBuffer.ToArray();
    string bodyText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bodyBytes);
}
```

If I write out the body to a file, the JSON is valid with no truncation.

```
string bodyContent = await new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();    
await File.WriteAllTextAsync("logs/bodyContent.txt", bodyContent);
```

I should mention that this is part of a .Net Core 6.0 Minimal API application.

I attempted different encodings as well but no luck.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: So, when you check bodyContent at debugger at this case : 
'string bodyContent = await new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();    
await File.WriteAllTextAsync("logs/bodyContent.txt", bodyContent); ' 
Is it contains all symbols?

Comment: The integration scenario is as follows. We have a Jira webhook that posts to the service I'm working on. The Request body contains the result from the webhook. I'm extracting the value from HttpContext.Request.Body. I'm writing out the body results to the service console and to files to figure this out. As I stated above, I'm attempting to write the body to a variable where I can extract a section from the JSON.

Comment: The body looks good other then it missing the last 2 curly braces. Again, writing to a file has the complete valid JSON.

Comment: Is bodyContent at debugger missed two curly braces, but file contains it?

Comment: How do you call method? From swagger, curl, third program call it?

Comment: Also try to check httpContext.Request.ContentLength is length equals with bodyContent.Length?

Comment: The service has been deployed to a server (e.g. server B). Jira webhooks require SSL and also runs on a server (e.g. Server A). I would have to set up remote debugging which is difficult though not impossible. Jira posts content to my service about an issue that was updated. I originally thought that the content being sent from Jira was invalid since I'm attempting to parse out the JSON using NewtonSoft which was throwing an exception about invalid JSON. I wrote it to the console - misses last 2 curly braces. Wrote it to file and it's whole. My code is above.

Comment: I'm thinking that it's related to the async processing or the stream and how or when it's flushed. I will check the length though which will tell me if the content length (in memory) is the same length as the file once it's written out. If the lengths are the same, that would support the issue with streaming/async. I will post my results. It's an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing out the body contents to the console using Serilog and Serilog was misbehaving or I was not using it correctly since the last 2 curly braces were missing. I compared the lengths (as @progpow suggested :)) of the body in memory and the file I wrote out to and they were the same. I was then able to run my service locally and executing the post via Postman using the file contents as the body. This allowed me to debug and find an issue with my parsing logic using NewtonSoft. I incorrectly assumed that what Serilog was writing out was what was being parsed.

Comment: If that is the solution to your issue I would suggest 2 things: Edit your answer and provide the answer there as well, stating that is what you found out. And on the other hand, put your answer as accepted (if that's allowed for you)